# Не работает вызов диалога dialog.show внутри ClickableSpan

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Помогите, пожалуйста, выдает ошибку при попытке вызвать диалог из метода `ClickableSpan`.
В `MainActivity` `OnCreate` я создаю экземпляр диалога:

```
WordTranslateDialogFragment dialog = new WordTranslateDialogFragment();
```

И потом внутри метода `ClickableSpan` пытаюсь вызвать диалог:

```
public ClickableSpan getClickableSpan(final String word) {
        return new ClickableSpan() {

            String mWord;{
                mWord = word;
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "клик на " + mWord);
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
                Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity. вызвал диалог ClickableSpan") ;
            }
        };
    }
```

Класс самого диалога:

```
  public class WordTranslateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

        final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getDialog().setTitle("Title!");
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog1, null);
            v.findViewById(R.id.btnYes).setOnClickListener(this);
            return v;
        }
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dialog 1: " + ((Button) v).getText());
            dismiss();
        }
    }
```

При клике на слово в методе `ClickableSpan` приложение закрывается и выдает ошибку:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void my.soulfly.entraining.WordTranslateDialogFragment.show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

с указанием на строку
**dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dlg1");**

Этот же диалог нормально вызывается, если навесить его на кнопку внутри OnCreate
Как это можно поправить?

Comment: В onCreate вы записываете экземпляр диалога в локальную переменную dialog, а где у вас он записывается в поле dialog которое используется в onClick? Судя по NullPointerException нигде...

Comment: Нет, я сначала объявляю переменную перед OnCreate

Comment: Я сначала объявляю переменную перед OnCreate, а потом внутри него создаю экземпляр dialog = new WordTranslateDialogFragment();
Если сразу создать объект диалога внутри метода ClickableSpan то выдант другую ошибку: Activity has been destroyed at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction с указанием на ту же строку